# Would it be better to render a whole template again or use jquery to modify a few values?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, backbone.js

Lets take for example the following template:

```
<div class="picture">
    <img src="<%= model.get("url") %>"></img>
    <p class="author"><%= model.get("author") %></p>
    <p class="date"><%= model.get("date") %></p>
    <div class="likers"><%= some logic that outputs a nice list of people that have liked this picture %></div>
    <button class="like-button <%= model.get("is_liked") ? 'active' : '' %>"><%= model.get("is_liked") ? 'You liked this picture' : 'Click here to like this picture' %></button>
</div>
```

Lets say I render that template using Backbone and clicking the like-button triggers the following function:

Option A:

```
var me = "Peeter";
var model; //refrence to the model 

var likers = model.get("likers");

model.get("is_liked") ? likers.remove(me) : likers.add(me); //Add/remove me
model.set({
    "is_liked" : !model.get("is_liked"), //Toggle state
    likers : likers
}); 

var $button = $(".like-button")
var $likers = $(".likers");

$button.toggleClass("active");
$button.hasClass("active") ? $button.text('You liked this picture') ? $button.text('Click here to like this picture');

$likers.text(/* copy/paste the logic that's in the  template to render the list of likers*/);
```

Option B:

```
var me = "Peeter";
var model; //refrence to the model 
var template; //refrence to the template declared at the top of this question

var likers = model.get("likers");

model.get("is_liked") ? likers.remove(me) : likers.add(me); //Add/remove me
model.set({
    "is_liked" : !model.get("is_liked"), //Toggle state
    likers : likers
}); 

template.render();
```

Which one of the methods would you recommend? Why? Also please take into count a mobile browser, is re-rendering an entire template (if the template was a bit bigger) a bit too slow on a mobile device?

Comment: I'd recommend that you try both and profile them to see which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that cannot be answered in general and some profiling for your specific use case will certainly help.

But as a general answer I think you have to review to following points:

1. Size of the template and the resulting time to process it with data
2. Number of events that you bind to your view. The more, the more you need to bind and unbind with every re-rendering
3. Your render function and how you have set it up as significant influence.

For more detais, please check these links:

- http://ianstormtaylor.com/break-apart-your-backbonejs-render-methods/
- http://ianstormtaylor.com/assigning-backbone-subviews-made-even-cleaner/
- http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/

Comment: I don't think #2 is valid. If I'm correct (feel free to correct me if I'm not), Backbone simply delegates all events from $el, meaning you don't specifically bind any events on view elements.

Comment: Read the 3rd link and you will see that it is valid, I also was not aware of this before.

Comment: I did, I'm not following on how that happens though. You re-render your subviews when you render your main view?

Comment: First of all, you can separate the rendering of views and subviews and also various elements of one view, Ian Taylor has demonstrated that in details in the 3 articles by just plugging the elements together without rendering them. Second, with a "normal" template rendering you dump your current element's content and create a new one - thus either you unbind events or you end up with zombies and then you need to rebind - checkout the section "Unbinding DOM events by accident" of the first article.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the update via JQuery. JQuery small updates are fairly quick even on 600 MHz android.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to bind your UI element to your model with [Backbone ModelBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder).
It's the best wait to update small UI section without re-render the whole template.